# ADB install: rm failed for '/data/local/tmp/app.apk': Read-only file system

Tags: android, adb, apk, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to install application to Android Emulator using command "abd install app.apk". It's processsed and I receive error, that it cann't be deleted, because it's 'read-only file system'.
I'm trying to 'chmod' data folder, but 'read-only file system'.

AVD properties:
Android 4.4.2 (API Level 19)
CPU: ARM
Internal Storage & SD Card: 1024 MiB

How can I change access right to this folder? Already tried to 'adb remount' and remount from emulator terminal.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `/data/local/tmp` is normally writable. I would guess that there is something wrong with your AVD - so just recreate it from scratch

Answer (score 0):

There was something wrong with AVD or API. I created new configuration with API Level 24 and it helped.